# unexpected information in Json

Tags: json, java-8, spring-data-jpa

I have simple rest service on spring.

when I send request to

```
@GetMapping(value = "/{id}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
   public KnowledgeBaseEntity getArticle(@PathVariable Long id) {
       return knowledgeBaseRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow(
() -> new KnowledgeBaseNotFoundException(id));
   }
```

I get normal Json response but also unexpected field "new". e.g.

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "key_values": [
        "Lorem",
        "ipsum",
        "amet",
        "luctus"
    ],
    "article": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis luctus turpis vel viverra dapibus",
    "caption": "Lorem ipsum",
    "new": false
}
```

My entity has only id, key_values, article and caption fields. And one JsonIgnore field which I use only for database storage but not for serialization/deserialization.

how can I get rid of this additional field in response?

Edit:
My entity is

```
@Entity(name = "KnowledgeBase")
@Table(name = "knowledge_base")
@Getter
@Setter
public class KnowledgeBaseEntity extends AbstractEntity<Long> {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "key_values", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "json")
    @Type(type = "my.test.StringJsonType")
    @JsonIgnore
    private String keys;

    @Transient
    private String[] key_values;

    @NotEmpty
    private String article;

    private  String caption;
    //...@PrePersist and @PostLoad member functions. Omitted for less code
}
```

Comment: Have you used `@JsonIgnore` annotation?

Comment: Can you please add in your question the entity content

Comment: @HassamAbdelillah I updated my post with messege

Comment: Just to be sure AbstractEntity in you snippet is spring-data class or your own ?

Comment: It's @MappedSuperclass:
public abstract class AbstractEntity<ID> implements Persistable<ID>, Serializable

Comment: I found out that problem was with isNew() in Persistable. So i just added Override with JsonIgnore and now everything works fine, thanks @HassamAbdelillah. It's your comment that pointed me in right direction